# How can I add my data without "for" loop in my List?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

There is a movies table. I added films of every customer to List. How can I add these elements of list without array to class that can receive inheritance from `List<string>`?

```
int sayici = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < filmler.Count; )
{
    List<string> flm = new List<string>();
    n = new varliklar.kisi_film_listesi();
    for (int j = i + 1; j < (filmler.Count - 1); j++)
    {
        if (filmler[i]._CustomerID == filmler[j]._CustomerID)
        {
            flm.Add(filmler[j - 1]._Movie);
            sayici++;
        }
    }

    Veri nesneVeri = new Veri();
    n._CumtomerID = filmler[i]._CustomerID;
    n._movies = flm;
    // I WANT TO CHANGE THIS "for" LOOP, I WANT TO ADD WITHOUT ARRAY
    for (int a = 0; a < flm.Count; a++)
    {
        nesneVeri.Add(flm[a]);
    }
    db.Add(nesneVeri);
    i += sayici + 1;
    sayici = 0;
}
```

This is also my Data class below

```
public class Veri : List<String>
{
    public double Destek { get; set; }
    public bool Contains(Veri veriler)
    {
        return (this.Intersect(veriler).Count() == veriler.Count);
    }
    public Veri Remove(Veri veriler)
    {
        Veri removed = new Veri();
        removed.AddRange(from item in this
                         where !veriler.Contains(item)
                         select item);
        return (removed);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ("{" + string.Join(", ", this.ToArray()) + "}" + (this.Destek > 0 ? " (Destek: " + Math.Round(this.Destek, 2) + "%)" : string.Empty));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inheritance from List"  You mean you want to be able to use lists instead of arrays?

Comment: You are right but I already used Addrange() and It is occured errors due to my Veri class

Comment: What errors did you get when you used AddRange() ?

Answer (score 3):

Well this loop:

```
for (int a = 0; a < flm.Count; a++)
{
    nesneVeri.Add(flm[a]);
}
```

is the same as:

```
nesneVeri.AddRange(flm);
```

The `List<T>.AddRange` function can take any `IEnumerable<T>`, so it will work with a list *or* an array.  But I'm not sure what the actual issue is.

Comment: However I want to send from Veri class to Veritoplami class                           `code public class VeriToplami: List<Veri>`

Comment: @TanjuUralkaya this post answers the question as it is asked. If you wanted to ask something else either edit the question (probably will not be really nice to existing answers) or better yet ask new specific question.

Comment: What is the `Veritoplomi` class (other than a `List<Veri>`)?  What do you mean by "send it to"?

Answer (score 0):

Because the class `Veri` inherits from `List<string>` you can use the [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `List` class.

In your example, you can replace the `for` loop you want to change with this line of code.

```
nesneVeri.AddRange(flm)
```

Comment: However I want to send from Veri class to Veritoplami class code public class VeriToplami: List<Veri>

Comment: There another class named `Veritoplami` that inherits from `List<Veri>`.  This class is not used in your example code. If you want to add a List of Veri objects to a Veritoplami list, you can use the AddRange method there too.

Perhaps you can update your example, or add a second example, that is using a Veritoplami object. Include any errors you are getting with the Veritoplami object. It might be easier to understand you are trying to do and help with any problems.